# Can't sign in to Bitbucket Cloud account in Xcode. error: "Your account or password is incorrect"

Tags: xcode, bitbucket

I clicked "Create a Password on Bitbucket Cloud" and it generated a 36-char alphnum pw.

Sign in fails with anything I put in Account or Password.

I don't know what Xcode means by "Account"?
Is it the Label? Username? email?  Atlassian account or my Atlassian account's Bitbucket personal settings?

And for password, does Xcode want the 36-char password of Bitbucket personal settings app or password of my Bitbucket's Atassian account?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The account name you use is the username, not the email address associated with your Bitbucket cloud account. You can locate your username by navigating to your Bitbucket Personal settings page and then you can see your username will be located under Bitbucket profile settings. Here are the instructions from Bitbucket: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/using-app-passwords/